# Need help understanding a rotary encoder datasheet

Tags: pcb, schematics, datasheet, encoder, keyboard

I am trying to design a keyboard and have come across the realization that the datasheet for my rotary encoder asks for 5k resistors connected to terminals A and B of the encoder.

However I am having trouble understanding how the encoder should be wired.

1. Should the terminals be connected to power as well as specific pins like this?

[image: Terminals connected to VCC]

2. Or would the pins provide the power for the terminals and all I have to do is connect the resistors to the wire connected to the pins?

[image: Terminals connected directly to pins]

The datasheet schematic for the component is:

[image: Datasheet schematic]

The micro-controller I am using is the AT90USB646-AU in case that is some info that is needed as well.

Comment: I hope you have a debouncer.

Comment: if you turn on the AT90USB internal pull-ups you won't need the pull-up resistors.

Answer (score 3):

If the schematic is to be believed, that encoder has mechanical switches.  That means that it doesn't need to be powered -- you just need the pull-up resistors so that when an encoder switch is open, the corresponding pin is high.

Comment: No active components inside so no dedicated power terminal needed.

Comment: So it would be wired like the second image then?

Comment: No, like the first image.  *It's just a pair of switches*.  How would you connect a plain old switch as an input to your micro?

Answer (score 2):

The encoder is literally a mechanical switch (or 3 switches if you prefer- the two phased encoder switches and the independent push switch). Here is what is inside one of them:

[image]

The inner two fingers are connected to the center terminal. The outer bifurcated fingers go to the two outer terminals.

Not shown is a dome contact that bridges the two inner concentric contacts when the shaft is pressed.

Here is the rotating part:

[image]

There is a spring detent mechanism that lines up the contacts (something like 20 detents per 360° on this one).

So it needs no power, the pullup resistors give you a 0/5V signal which your MCU needs to read (and debounce, and interpret as a count).

Comment: So the 2 5k resistors basically function as a buffer until the encoder essentially "shoots" out the full 5V signal?

Comment: The resistor pulls the input to +5 when the switch is open, when the switch closes it shorts the input to ground (0V).

Answer (score 0):

The schematic you show from the datasheet clearly shows resistors connected from the encoder output pins to +5V.  They are pull-up resistors used to ensure that the encoder outputs will be seen has a logic High by following logic inputs when the switch is open.